# When does Kotlin introspection become available in the lifetime of a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-mongodb, kotlin-reflect

I ran into a surprising bug. I am trying to make an application that would access mongodb using the *repository pattern*. In order to reduce code duplication I wanted to make a common base class for all repositories. The repository of each root aggregate (such as `Person` in code bellow), would inherit from this `RepositoryBase` and inherit all the common functionality.

```
data class Person(val name: String)

open class RepositoryBase<T: Any> (val template: ReactiveMongoTemplate, private val klass: KClass<T>)
{
    fun count(): Mono<Long> = template.count(Query(), klass.java)
}

@Repository
class PersonRepository(template: ReactiveMongoTemplate): RepositoryBase<Person>(template, Person::class)

@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests
{
    @Autowired var personRepository: PersonRepository? = null

    @Test
    fun contextLoads()
    {
        println(personRepository?.count()?.block()!!)
    }
}
```

However, this does not seem to work:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is
>   null: method kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass, parameter
>   $receiver
>
> at kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass(JvmClassMapping.kt)    at
>   com.example.demo.RepositoryBase.count(DemoApplicationTests.kt:18)
>   ...

It seems that at the time `Person::class` is being called, the introspection capabilities are not fully initialized and the subsequent call to `KClass.java`, which is defined as:

```
/**
 * Returns a Java [Class] instance corresponding to the given [KClass] instance.
 */
@Suppress("UPPER_BOUND_VIOLATED")
public val <T> KClass<T>.java: Class<T>
    @JvmName("getJavaClass")
    get() = (this as ClassBasedDeclarationContainer).jClass as Class<T>
```

results in the null-exception.

I would like to know if there are some rules on using introspection in Spring applications or whether this is a bug either in Kotlin or in Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR;

It looks like a bug, but it isn't – it's a consequence of how things work.

### Explanation

What happens here is that `private val klass: KClass<T>` is `null`. Looking at the code, this actually can't happen, but it does. What happens behind the scenes is that Spring creates a proxy for `PersonRepository`:

```
this = {com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests@5173} 
 personRepository = {com.example.demo.PersonRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42849208@5193} "com.example.demo.PersonRepository@1961d75a"
  CGLIB$BOUND = false
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_0 = {org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor@5208} 
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_1 = {org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$StaticUnadvisedInterceptor@5209} 
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_2 = {org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$SerializableNoOp@5210} 
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_3 = {org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$StaticDispatcher@5211} 
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_4 = {org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$AdvisedDispatcher@5212} 
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_5 = {org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$EqualsInterceptor@5213} 
  CGLIB$CALLBACK_6 = {org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$HashCodeInterceptor@5214} 
  template = null
  klass = null
```

As you can see, `klass` is `null`. This is a significant fact because you're calling `RepositoryBase.count()`. `count()` is `final`, therefore it can't be proxied by CGLIB. Inside of `count()` you're accessing the `klass` field (not using a getter here) therefore the call uses the uninitialized field from the proxy instance instead of the actual target. Using a getter method would route the call to the actual target and retrieve the field.

### Solution

Make your method non-`final`:

```
open class RepositoryBase<T: Any> (val template: ReactiveMongoTemplate, private val klass: KClass<T>)
{
    open fun count(): …
}
```